# Stopping Time with local martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

I am working on Karatzas&Shreve Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus P.36, Problem 5.19.

• (i) A local martingale of class DL is a martingale.

• (ii) A nonnegative local martingale is a supermartingale.

• (iii) If $M\in\mathscr{M}^{c,loc}$ and $S$ is a stopping time of $\left\{ \mathscr{F}_{t}\right\}$  then $E\left(M_{S}^{2}\right)\le E\left\langle M\right\rangle _{S}$ where $M_{\infty}^{2}={\displaystyle \liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}M_{t}^{2}}$. $\mathscr{M}^{c,loc}$ donate the space of continuous local martingale.

I have solved (i) and (ii). But I am trapped in (iii).
By definition, we know $M^{2}-\left\langle M\right\rangle\in\mathscr{M}^{c,loc}$. But I don't know what to next. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a localizing sequence $\{T_n\}$ for $X=M^2-\langle M\rangle$. Since $X^{S\wedge T_n}$ is a u.i. martingale, $\mathsf{E}X_{S\wedge T_n}=0$ for each $n\ge 1$. Using Fatou's lemma,
$$
\mathsf{E}M_S^2\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}M_{S\wedge T_n}^2=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}\langle M\rangle_{S\wedge T_n}=\mathsf{E}\langle M\rangle_S.
$$

Comment: Sorry.. I have trouble in understanding "Since $X_{S\wedge T_{n}}$ is a u.i. martingale, so $EX_{S\wedge T_{n}}=0$". Why $X_{S\wedge T_{n}}$  is a u.i. martingale? and why $EX_{S\wedge T_{n}}=0$? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: I might mistype the comment. I know that $X^{S\wedge T_{n}}$ is a martingale, but why is it u.i.? If it is u.i., we can let $t$ goes to $\infty$ to get $EX_{S\wedge T_{n}}=0$, right?

Comment: That's by the definition of local martingales (i.e $X^{T_n}$ is a u.i. MTG for each $n\ge 1$) and the optional sampling theorem.

Comment: Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636142/local-martingale-is-locally-uniformly-integrable-martingale/1329908) question.

Comment: Yeah, now it looks sensible to me. Thanks for your answer.